# Is there any way to generate response model with generic result property for incoming nested response?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my results property of Pagination would be generic list.
But cannot convert into generic list.
I'm getting _InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Movie.

I want results to be generic type of list.

```
   class Pagination<T> {
       final int page;
       final List<T> results;
       final int total_pages;
       final int total_results;
   }
```

and my fromJson method is like this:

```
  factory Pagination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['results'];
    List<T> res = new List<T>.from(list);
    return Pagination(
      page: json['page'],
      results: res,
      total_pages: json['total_pages'],
      total_results: json['total_results']
    );
  }
```

and then i'm getting this error

```
_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Movie'
```

Comment: You need a way to deserialize 'result` into `T`

Comment: How can I deserialize result?

Comment: Looks like `json.results` is having List of Jsons (i.e. List<Map<String, dynamic>>) but you are trying to build List<Movie> from it. So you might want to have `Movie.fromJson` and use it. Instead of writing all these serialization and deserialization methods better to use https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable.